# How to exit Mocha after test execution?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, istanbul

I want mocha to exit after executing all the tests, so that Istanbul can check the code coverage, I used `--exit` in my `package.json` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Am I missing something ?

```
"scripts": {
"test": "istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha test/Testcases/ --exit" 
 }
```

All test files are under `test/Testcases/` folder and mocha should exit after executing them all

P.S. I am using windows OS so I am referring the bin file manually.

Answer (score 3):

Using `--exit` should works.

By the way, I use this, I think is more flexible to execute with or without coverage:

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha tests --timeout 4000 --reporter mochawesome --exit",
    "coverage": "nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text npm run test"
  }
```

So if you run `npm run test` you will get only tests, but using `npm run coverage` the coverage will be displayed too.

Note that `coverage` follow this pattern:

`nyc + arguments + mocha execution`

But using only one line, this also works:

```json
"test": "nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha tests --timeout 4000 --reporter mochawesome --exit"
```

Removing extra arguments:

```json
"test": "nyc --reporter=html mocha tests --exit"
```